# Group By Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I have document A, B, C in the same document type. All 3 has a property is_type = 'Normal', is_type = 'Normal', is_type = 'AbNormal'. I want to get search Response in one single query and then just use Search Response API to get the list of Documents which were having type as normal and abnormal. I know aggregation will not help in getting the document as it's just aggregation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Make it clear. You just want to find the documents of type `normal` and `abnormal` ?

Comment: Yes, i just want to bucket them in a single request to ES.. I don't want to get all documents and then segregate doing iteration..